# Calculations between two columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new `expected` column based on two other columns. A new column is created by adding the value from column `const` and subtracting the value from column `value`.

My data:

```
df<-data.frame(product = rep(c('A','B'),each=4), data = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-04"), by = "day"),
               value = c(10, 15, 0, 5, 20, 5, 10, 0), const = c(100, 0, 10, 0, 100, 0, 0, 10), 
               expected = c(90, 75, 85, 80, 80, 75, 65, 75))

> df
  product       data value const expected
1       A 2020-01-01    10   100       90
2       A 2020-01-02    15     0       75
3       A 2020-01-03     0    10       85
4       A 2020-01-04     5     0       80
5       B 2020-01-01    20   100       80
6       B 2020-01-02     5     0       75
7       B 2020-01-03    10     0       65
8       B 2020-01-04     0    10       75
```

Edit data:

```
TD<-data.frame(product = rep("A",4), data = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-04"), by = "day"),
               value = c(15, 1, 2, 1, 0), value2 = c(10, 0, 10, 0, 100))

TD <- TD %>% group_by(product) %>%  mutate(expected1 = cumsum(value2) - cumsum(value))

TD
  product data       value value2 expected1
  <fct>   <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A       2020-01-01    15     10        -5
2 A       2020-01-02     1      0        -6
3 A       2020-01-03     2     10         2
4 A       2020-01-04     1      0         1
5 A       2020-01-05     0    100       101

TD_expected
 product       data value value2 expected1
1       A 2020-01-01    15     10        -5
2       A 2020-01-02     1      0        -6
3       A 2020-01-03     2     10         8
4       A 2020-01-04     1      0         7
5       A 2020-01-05     0    100       107
```

**NOTE:** When the value2 is greater than the value1, we assign the value2 to the expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `base R`, where `ave()` and `cumsum()` are applied to get the `expected`:

- For original data `df`:

```
dfs <- split(df,df$product)
df <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  within(x, expected <- ave(const-value,
                             ave(const-value,
                                 cumsum(const>value),FUN = cumsum)>0,FUN = cumsum))
}))
```

such that

```
> df
  product       data value const expected
1       A 2020-01-01    10   100       90
2       A 2020-01-02    15     0       75
3       A 2020-01-03     0    10       85
4       A 2020-01-04     5     0       80
5       B 2020-01-01    20   100       80
6       B 2020-01-02     5     0       75
7       B 2020-01-03    10     0       65
8       B 2020-01-04     0    10       75
```

- For edited data `DT`:
  you can use

```
TDs <- split(TD,TD$product)
TD <- Reduce(rbind,lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  within(x, expected <- ave(value2-value,
                             ave(value2-value,
                                 cumsum(value2>value),FUN = cumsum)>0,FUN = cumsum))
}))
```

such that

```
> TD
  product       data value value2 expected
1       A 2020-01-01    15     10       -5
2       A 2020-01-02     1      0       -6
3       A 2020-01-03     2     10        8
4       A 2020-01-04     1      0        7
5       A 2020-01-05     0    100      107
```

Comment: @Zizou why it is `-5, -6, 8, 7`? No clue how you calculate it....

Comment: When the value2 is greater than the value1, we assign the value2 to the expected

Comment: @Zizou I have updated my solution for both your original data `df` and newly edited data `DT`. The approaches is with `base R`. Please check it out...

Comment: The solution works, but I added a 5th row in the data and then it counts incorrectly, I need 107 instead of 100.

Comment: @Zizou Why 107? You have different calculation method for row 3 and row 5?

Comment: Because when negative is expected ```-6```, we rewrite the value as in your solution. But if it's positive ```7``` I have to add it to the previous expected value.

Comment: @Zizou Now I updated the solutions for both `df` and `TD`, please check it if this is what you want....

Comment: @Zizou I don't think the answer you accepted from Ronak Shah can reach your objective....

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ave` and `cumsum`.

```
df$expected <- ave(df$const - df$value, df$product, FUN=cumsum)
df
#  product       data value const expected
#1       A 2020-01-01    10   100       90
#2       A 2020-01-02    15     0       75
#3       A 2020-01-03     0    10       85
#4       A 2020-01-04     5     0       80
#5       B 2020-01-01    20   100       80
#6       B 2020-01-02     5     0       75
#7       B 2020-01-03    10     0       65
#8       B 2020-01-04     0    10       75
```

Comment: I was editing my data because for negative values the solution does not work as I would like.

Comment: Afer your have *edited your question* it looks like you want something like: `tt <- 0; ID  <- TD$product[1]; sapply(seq_len(nrow(TD)), function(i) {if(ID != TD$product[i]) {ID <- TD$product[i]; tt <- 0}; if(tt < 0 & TD$value2[i] > TD$value[i]) {tt <<- TD$value2[i] - TD$value[i]; } else {tt <<- tt + TD$value2[i] - TD$value[i]}; tt})`

Answer (score 2):

You could take `cumsum` of `const` and `value` by group and then subtract

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(product) %>%  mutate(expected1 = cumsum(const) - cumsum(value))

#  product data       value const expected expected1
#  <fct>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 A       2020-01-01    10   100       90        90
#2 A       2020-01-02    15     0       75        75
#3 A       2020-01-03     0    10       85        85
#4 A       2020-01-04     5     0       80        80
#5 B       2020-01-01    20   100       80        80
#6 B       2020-01-02     5     0       75        75
#7 B       2020-01-03    10     0       65        65
#8 B       2020-01-04     0    10       75        75
```

---

Using base R that can be done by

```
df$expected1 <- with(df, ave(const, product, FUN = cumsum) - 
                         ave(value, product, FUN = cumsum))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, expected1 := cumsum(const) - cumsum(value), product]
```

---

**EDIT**

For the update, we can create a new group and follow the same process.

```
TD %>% 
  group_by(product, group = cumsum(value2 > value)) %>%
  mutate(expected1 = cumsum(value2) - cumsum(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

# product data       value value2 expected1
#  <fct>   <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 A       2020-01-01    15     10        -5
#2 A       2020-01-02     1      0        -6
#3 A       2020-01-03     2     10         8
#4 A       2020-01-04     1      0         7
```

Comment: I was editing my data because for negative values the solution does not work as I would like.

Comment: @Zizou Can you explain the calculation ? How do you get 8 for 3rd row ?

Comment: When the value2 is greater than the value1, we assign the value2 to the expected

Comment: @Zizou Updated the answer. Please check the **EDIT**.

Comment: The solution works, but I added a 5th row in the data and then it counts incorrectly, I need 107 instead of 100.

Comment: Can you look at this?

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this in `tidyverse` with single `cumsum` similar to `ave` option from @GKi's post

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(product) %>%
   mutate(expected1 = cumsum(const - value))
```

Comment: I was editing my data because for negative values the solution does not work as I would like.