# Subtracting values between columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to create a new column by adding value from the stock column and subtracting the value from the sales column. When the result is negative, the next stock should be rewritten to the results as in the example. With the help of ThomasIsCoding the created code works well for sample data. But when I test the program for many products, there are erroneous calculations. Which shows below. Can you check why this is happening?

**Code:**

```
TD<-data.frame(product = rep("A",9), data = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-09"), by = "day"),
               sale = c(0, 5, 0, 0, 15, 1, 2, 1, 0), stock = c(0, 0, 50, 0,  10, 0, 10, 0, 100))
TD <- within(TD, result <- ave(stock-sale, product,
                              ave(stock-sale,
                               cumsum(stock>sale),FUN = cumsum)>0,FUN = cumsum))

> TD#works well
  product       data sale stock   result
1       A 2020-01-01    0     0        0
2       A 2020-01-02    5     0       -5
3       A 2020-01-03    0    50       50
4       A 2020-01-04    0     0       50
5       A 2020-01-05   15    10       45
6       A 2020-01-06    1     0       44
7       A 2020-01-07    2    10       52
8       A 2020-01-08    1     0       51
9       A 2020-01-09    0   100      151
```

**Examples when it doesn't work:**
I don't understand why the program sometimes works well and sometimes it doesn't.

```
> TD[1330:1340,]#doesn't work
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:  data [4]
   product data       stock  sale   result      expected
   <chr>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 B       2020-02-25     0     0      -21           -21
 2 B       2020-02-26     0     0      -21           -21
 3 B       2020-02-27    60     4       35            56
 4 B       2020-02-28     0     2       33            54

> TD[7293:7297,]#works ok
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   data [5]
   product  data       stock  sale   result      
   <chr>    <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 D        2020-01-13     0     2      -22
 2 D        2020-01-14     0     2      -24
 3 D        2020-01-15     0     0      -24
 4 D        2020-01-16   100     2       98
 5 D        2020-01-17     0     4       94
```

Comment: *"there are erroneous calculations"* Why are they erroneous? Can you provide sample data (for the cases that did *not* work) and expected output in a reproducible format (not as a picture).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "When the result is negative, the next stock should be rewritten to the results" ? Also as mentioned b @MauritsEvers, please provide an expected output. I tried with adding various factor and I don't have anything wrong in the formula

Comment: @dc37 this can be seen in the example between the second and third rows. It works fine.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I add column expected.

Comment: You have been changing your conditions again and again. You really need to define your conditions correctly. Are you clear about it yourself first? Think clearly with a fresh mind what needs to be done in which cases. In your previous question in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267617/calculations-between-two-columns-in-a-data-frame-in-r/) you mention that result should be carry forwarded if the value is negative. Here for row number 1333 you have expected value as 56 even when the previous value is negative(-21). Please be clear on what you want to do under what conditions.

Comment: @Ronak Shah yes, the result should be carry forwarded if the value is negative, but if there is a sale then we count it as well. Hence the result 56, not 60 for row number 1333.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, maybe this is a solution, definitely not the most elegant or readable but at least it passes all your "test" dataframes:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(New = stock - sale) %>%
  mutate(New2 = ifelse(lag((stock-sale) <0), stock, stock-sale)) %>%
  mutate(New3 = ifelse(is.na(New2),New, New2)) %>%
  mutate(New4 = ifelse(lag(New3 >= 0), lag(New3)+stock-sale,New3)) %>%
  mutate(New4 = ifelse(is.na(New4),stock-sale,New4)) %>%
  select(product, sale, stock, Result = New4)
```

So, now testing a dataframe with multiple groups:

```r
TD2 = data.frame(product = c("AA","AA","AA","AA","AZ","AZ","AZ","AF","AF","AF","BA","BA","BA"), 
                 data = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-13"), by = "day"),
                 sale = c(0, 5, 0, 0, 15, 1, 2, 1, 0,10,0,1,10), 
                 stock = c(0, 0, 50, 0,  10, 0, 10, 0, 100,0,0,100,0))

TD2 %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(New = stock - sale) %>%
  mutate(New2 = ifelse(lag((stock-sale) <0), stock, stock-sale)) %>%
  mutate(New3 = ifelse(is.na(New2),New, New2)) %>%
  mutate(New4 = ifelse(lag(New3 >= 0), lag(New3)+stock-sale,New3)) %>%
  mutate(New4 = ifelse(is.na(New4),stock-sale,New4)) %>%
  select(product, sale, stock, Result = New4)

# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   product [4]
   product  sale stock Result
   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 AA          0     0      0
 2 AA          5     0     -5
 3 AA          0    50     50
 4 AA          0     0     50
 5 AZ         15    10     -5
 6 AZ          1     0      0
 7 AZ          2    10      8
 8 AF          1     0     -1
 9 AF          0   100    100
10 AF         10     0     90
11 BA          0     0      0
12 BA          1   100     99
13 BA         10     0     89
```

Now testing the second example of your question (I assumed that `-21` in the expected results is an error and was in fact inherited from previous calculations and so I decided to ignore this results and focused only on the last part because getting -21 at this step does not make any sense based on your data):

```r
Test2 = data.frame(product = c("AA","AA","AA","AA"), 
                 sale = c(0, 0,4,2), 
                 stock = c(0, 0, 60, 0))

Test2 %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(New = stock - sale) %>%
  mutate(New2 = ifelse(lag((stock-sale) <0), stock, stock-sale)) %>%
  mutate(New3 = ifelse(is.na(New2),New, New2)) %>%
  mutate(New4 = ifelse(lag(New3 >= 0), lag(New3)+stock-sale,New3)) %>%
  mutate(New4 = ifelse(is.na(New4),stock-sale,New4)) %>%
  select(product, sale, stock, Result = New4)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   product [1]
  product  sale stock Result
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AA          0     0      0
2 AA          0     0      0
3 AA          4    60     56
4 AA          2     0     54
```

And finally the last example of your question:

```r
Test3 = data.frame(product = c("AA","AA","AA","AA","AA"), 
                   sale = c(2,2,0,2,4), 
                   stock = c(0, 0, 0,100, 0))

Test3 %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(New = stock - sale) %>%
    mutate(New2 = ifelse(lag((stock-sale) <0), stock, stock-sale)) %>%
    mutate(New3 = ifelse(is.na(New2),New, New2)) %>%
    mutate(New4 = ifelse(lag(New3 >= 0), lag(New3)+stock-sale,New3)) %>%
    mutate(New4 = ifelse(is.na(New4),stock-sale,New4)) %>%
    select(product, sale, stock, Result = New4)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   product [1]
  product  sale stock Result
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AA          2     0     -2
2 AA          2     0      0
3 AA          0     0      0
4 AA          2   100     98
5 AA          4     0     94
```

Hope that it will be satisfying for you. Otherwise, as mentioned in comments by @RonakShah, I invited you to re-consider your approach to clearly defined what you need, how to calculate it and what is the rationale of your output.